# Vanilla Javascript - Close menu with swipe

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a responsive website without a JS framework.

The problem is that I want to swipe the navigation menu closed (#menu-wrapper) after it's opened, but 1) it doesn't close, and 2) the links are no longer 'clickable' by touching them.

Everything works on desktop using a mouse. Problems are with touch.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/pksml/pen/BKVwor

Codepen: http://codepen.io/pksml/full/BKVwor/

Question: How can I get links to work by touch and a left swipe to close the menu?

PS Here's some code since this site requires it :)

```
<div id="menu-link" class="pointer" style="">
<ul style=""><li style="" onclick='
document.getElementById("menu-wrapper").style.transform = "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)";
document.getElementById("menu-wrapper").style.WebkitTransform = "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)";
document.getElementById("menu-wrapper").style.MozTransform = "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)";
'>&#x2261; Open Menu</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You will eventually use a library... And when you do Hammer.js is great. Just sayin'

Comment: Have a look at touch events: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml